# Can still access LAMP server, even after deleting local ssh keys

Tags: ssh, lamp, ssh-keys

Server newbie here and on a mac for reference.

So I'm trying to break my ssh key authentication between me and my LAMP stack although I can't. In other words, it just gives me access and I don't know how! Here's what I've done...

- Created a key via terminal: `ssh-keygen -f foo_key`
- Stuck the pub key in the correct place on my server...
- ssh'ed in via terminal: `ssh -i /Users/me/.ssh/foo_key root@x.x.x.x`
- It's asked for the password I chose upon setup, fine inputed that.

So now I have access, next I `logout` from my server. Now I want to rid access on this computer. I've tried removing my local private and public keys, I've tried removing the checksum in `known_hosts`, I've tried locating a key saved in `keychain access`, nothing there.

So where has this authentication information been saved, it's pretty annoying.

All guidance appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's some verbose info, it doesn't seem to be using my `foo_key` at all now:

```
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
```

No precise info on the RSA key it even frickin' offers in the first place:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Running -vvv doesn't give me any more meaningful information than what I have already posted. I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I don't have a `authorized_keys` file in `~/.ssh/`. I created one and generated some new keys, nothing gets stored in there.

I just need to know why I can continue accessing my server even after I've supposedly removed all evidence of the keys I generated on my machine. Can't believe this isn't common!?

It's worth noting, I'm not defaulting to the `id_rsa` keys, I'm specifically creating custom ones and want to continue using them.

Comment: post verbose log. It will tell you what is going on there.

Comment: I've posted some of it, any useful?

Comment: You are authenticating with some key. Using `-vvv` should give you even more information and hopefully also where does it take the key from.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks again, but no dice on anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any changes in sshd_config to disallow connections without public key authentication?

If no, you'll have to change the line saying

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Then you restart sshd with whatever init system you have.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how I get on.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: It's not or wasn't unrelated before the OPs edit. If you don't turn off PasswordAuthentication, then you will be able to log in to the server regardless of having a private key or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.ssh/foo_key` and `.ssh/foo_key.pub` from your local computer as well as remove the public key entry from the `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

The last step is the crucial one.

*Edit:* Also, you can use the `-v` option for more verbose output to see exactly how it authenticates.

Comment: Surely it shouldn't matter if the pub key still exists on the server? I removed both the public and private locally and could still gain access, which is the weird basis for my question.

Comment: @Capio That is true, just wanted to make sure to cover all the steps. `ssh -vvv` should be able to tell you what key/auth method it ends up using though. And check the authorized_keys file for any clues of other keys that might be added.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the keys locally from my mac and restarting, only then does it revoke access. So it must be caching the connection credentials somehow. Don't know how, but just incase someone is experiencing the same thing.